# Animation Scrolling Div with fixed navigation menu click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a navigation menu and above some div.

```css
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

    a:hover {
        background-color: fuchsia;
    }

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="divHeader">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in//images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="150px" />
    </div>
    <div id="Menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link Div 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Div 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Div 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link Div 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 <hr />
 <hr />
    <div id="content">
        <div id="Div1">
          <img src="http://www.clinks.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/anunciar-produtos-jovens-800x380.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="Div2">
  <img src="http://kitcheninterior.pics/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/GeoMATRIX-FlyAsh-Glass-Concrete-Countertops--800x380.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="Div3">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/94/7b/d1947bc25106297b762b3806233534bc.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="Div4"><img src="http://www.clinks.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/caracteres-especiais-links-patrocinados-800x380.jpg">
        </div></div>
```

I want to scroll div with the navigation click without changing the navigation links position and div scrolling position should be above the navigation menu.
Please help to create this thanks in advance

Comment: Try to this http://rohitazadmalik.blogspot.in/2014/03/section-have-fixed-position-when-it.html

Comment: I think i can do what you are asking for, but need to ask you one thing first. Your #Div1,2,3,4 which contains image would be of same height and width always? Than i can give you the solution to this.

Comment: Try with overflow: auto for your DIV(#content)

Answer (score 1):

Hi now used to this Jquery code and some change in your Navigation as like this

.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var target = this.hash,
     $target = $(target);

     $('html, body').stop().animate({
         'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
     }, 900, 'swing', function () {
         window.location.hash = target;
     });
 });
    
    
    var oritop = -100;
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollt = $(this).scrollTop();
    var elm = $(".scrollTopWindow");
    if(oritop < 0) {
        oritop= elm.offset().top;
    }
    if(scrollt >= oritop) {
        elm.css({"position": "fixed", "top": 0, "left": 0});
    }
    else {
        elm.css("position", "static");
    }


});
    
});
```

```css
ul {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

a {
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: purple;
    padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

    a:hover {
        background-color: fuchsia;
    }

li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divHeader">
        <img src="https://www.google.co.in//images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="150px" />
    </div>
    <div id="Menu" class="scrollTopWindow">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Div1">Link Div 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Div2">Link Div 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Div3">Link Div 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Div4">Link Div 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 <hr />
 <hr />
    <div id="content">
        <div id="Div1">
          <img src="http://www.clinks.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/anunciar-produtos-jovens-800x380.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="Div2">
  <img src="http://kitcheninterior.pics/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/GeoMATRIX-FlyAsh-Glass-Concrete-Countertops--800x380.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="Div3">
          <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/94/7b/d1947bc25106297b762b3806233534bc.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="Div4"><img src="http://www.clinks.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/caracteres-especiais-links-patrocinados-800x380.jpg">
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Sir but navigation position is not fixed

Comment: @Gitz Now  check  to my answer i have udpated this .

Comment: looks better ..but can it's possible to scroll these div inside the `content`

Comment: yes you can do it replace image tag with your content

Comment: I mean all page is not scroll only the div part is scroll when we click the menus..and the position of menus is fixed as it is

Comment: than you can used to jquery show, hide, fadeIn, fadeTo, fadeOut function .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting this solution...

Use `overflow: auto` `CSS` property to make your `div` scrollable and make it's position as `absolute` and it's parent `div` as `relative`.

Code snippets:

```css
ul {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        a {
            float: left;
            width: 6em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            background-color: purple;
            padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
            border-right: 1px solid white;
        }

            a:hover {
                background-color: fuchsia;
            }

        li {
            display: inline;
        }
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #wrapper:before {
            content: '';
            float: left;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #wrapper {
            height: 100%;
        }
        #content {
            position:relative;
        }
        #content:after {
            content: '';
            display: block;
            clear: both;
        }
        #scrollContent {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
            <div id="divHeader">
                <img src="https://www.google.co.in//images/srpr/logo11w.png" width="150px" />
            </div>
            <div id="Menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Div 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Div 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Div 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link Div 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <hr />
        <div id="content">
            <div id="scrollContent">
                <div id="Div1">
                    <img src="http://www.clinks.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/anunciar-produtos-jovens-800x380.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="Div2">
                    <img src="http://kitcheninterior.pics/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/GeoMATRIX-FlyAsh-Glass-Concrete-Countertops--800x380.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="Div3">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/d1/94/7b/d1947bc25106297b762b3806233534bc.jpg">
                </div>
                <div id="Div4">
                    <img src="http://www.clinks.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/caracteres-especiais-links-patrocinados-800x380.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope this helps you !!!